# Extend the list to left and right upto 50 percent of total length with continuous numbers

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist

I have few lists like,

```
l1=[8,9,10,11,12,13]
l2=[25,26,27,28,29]
```

Now I want to expand the list in both ways(50 percent of the length of the right and 50 percent to the left) with the continuous numbers.

so the output list will look like,

```
l1=[5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]
l2=[23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31]
```

I can do it using for loop, but Is there any python shortcut I am looking for.

Comment: What is wrong with a for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your list is an ordered list of integers, you could do something like:

```
l = [25,26,27,28,29]

length_l = len(l)
while len(l) < 2*length_l:
    l = [l[0]-1] + l + [l[-1]+1]

print(l)

# > [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]
```

but it can be done by just generating the list again with `range`, like this:

```
l = [8,9,10,11,12,13]

l = list(range(l[0]-len(l)//2, l[-1]+len(l)//2+1))

print(l)

# > [23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper function that adds the missing pieces:

```
l1=[8,9,10,11,12,13]
l2=[25,26,27,28,29]

def plusFifty(data):
    """Adds half the lists length worth of numbers to the begin and end of the list,
    decrementing from the first value and incrementing from the last value."""
    len_halfed = len(data) // 2 

    r = range(len_halfed)   # 0 ... len//2-1

    # now splice two list comps with the original list 
    return [data[0]-diff-1 for diff in r][::-1]+data+[data[-1]+diff+1 for diff in r]


print( plusFifty(l1))
print( plusFifty(l2))
```

Outputs

```
[5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14, 15, 16]
[23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 29, 30, 31]
```